# Flutter SQFlite Class to Json()

Tags: flutter, sqflite, data-storage

I am currently working on an app where the user is able to store data on their device locally. Therefor I am using the sqflite package but I am running into some errors converting my Class data into Json.
This is the error message I get:

> A value of type 'Set' can't be returned from the method
> 'toJson' because it has a return type of 'Map<String, Widget>'.
> due to this line:

```
Map<String, Widget> toJson() => {
            EntryFields.id = id,
            EntryFields.name = name,
            EntryFields.navigation = navigation,
          };
```

This is my class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const String tableFavs = 'favorites';

class EntryFields {
  static late String id = '_id';
  static late String name = '_name';
  static late String navigation = '_navigation';
}

class Entries {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final Widget navigation;

  Entries({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.navigation,
  });

  Map<String, Widget> toJson() => {
        EntryFields.id = id,
        EntryFields.name = name,
        EntryFields.navigation = navigation,
      };
}
```

and this is a snipped from my database:

```
  Future<Entries> create(Entries entries) async {
    final db = await instance.database;

    final id = await db.insert(tableFavs, entries.toJson());
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't store a widget in the database it should be Map<String, String>
try to store the parameters of the widget as a String, not the whole widget
you can store these types double, string, int, bool..

Answer (score 0):

try using the below code

```
class EntryFields {
  static late String id = '_id';
  static late String name = '_name';
  static late String navigation = '_navigation';
}

class Entries {
    const Entries({
        this.id,
        this.name,
        this.navigation,
    });

    final String? id;
    final String? name;
    final String? navigation;

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "_id": id,
        "_name": name,
        "_navigation": navigation,
    };
}

  Future<void> create(Entries entries) async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    final id = await db.insert(tableFavs, entries.toJson());
  }

void main(){
  final entriesFromField = Entries(
    id: EntryFields.id,
    name: EntryFields.name,
    navigation: EntryFields.navigation
  );
  
  create(entriesFromField);
  
}
```

or better you can use this [json generator](https://app.quicktype.io)